# Can I rely on google test for microdata on Organization and PostalAddress?

Tags: schema.org

I try to get a simple business address which I structured after the `https://schema.org/PostalAddress` Example 2:

```html
  <div class="place" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
    <p>
      <span itemprop="name">Organisation</span>
    </p>
    <p itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/PostalAddress">
      <span itemprop="streetAddress">Stationstreet 1</span>
      <span itemprop="postalCode">8596</span> <span itemprop="addressLocality">Arbon</span>
    </p>
  </div>
```

If I let [google test rich results](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) test this it claims that no data was detected. If I test on (https://validator.schema.org) it proofs to contain a proper address.
Is this a mistake on my end or shouldn't I trust Google's test here?

Comment: No rich result for `https://schema.org/Organization`. The best idea is to follow this docs:  https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/local-business?hl=en. Sub types: https://schema.org/LocalBusiness#subtypes

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Google’s [Rich Results Test tool](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) is showing/validating structured data that conforms to their own [Rich Results](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/search-gallery?hl=en). Rich Results are features in Google Search (typically for displaying a search result in a different way), which make use of certain Schema.org schemas. This means the tool only considers a very small subset of what is possible to describe with Schema.org.

You can see this in action if you replace your `Organization` type with the subtype `LocalBusiness` (just for testing; if your organization is not a local business, don’t publish it like that). The tool will detect an item then, because Google has a [rich result for local businesses](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/local-business?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks, what did work is the json+ld format . The problem is that it not really is a local bussiness perse but a public service (sewage management) but our customer still needs to increase visibility in search results, where it now appears pretty low.